# Formula for displaying unchecked choice options in another column

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a 'Choice' web part showing multiple checkboxes with where employees open a record and tick the checkbox next to their name to confirm they have read an update.

I need a formula for a calculated column which will list the names of all the folks who haven't checked the box.  Is this possible?

It strikes me that the data return options for calculated columns seem to indicate that it might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

A Calculated Column Formula can only reference Simple types.. so No Lookup Columns, No People Columns and No Multiple Choice Columns

You would need scripting to proces the contents of a filled Field and compare it with your total list of options

On 2013 you can use CSR (Client Side Rendering)

You could use a Workflow to write the Multiple Choice column to a Text Column

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I'm using a hosted version of Sharepoint and I'm not a coder or anything, but it'll help back-up my argument that we should get our own licence rather than using a limited hosted service.  Cheers.